# How to display image in Xamarin ListView from the uploads folder in the Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin

I created an ASP.Net Core API that uploads images to the server, now I need to display these images on the client-side (xamarin).
This is the model:

```cs
public class Machine
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Machine_Qr { get; set; }
    
    public string Machine_Name { get; set; }
        
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the controller for the uploading and adding the machine to the database:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<Machine>> Create([FromForm] Machine machine)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var file = machine.Image;
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse

            (file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

            System.Console.WriteLine(fileName);
            
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine("uploads", file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }         

        _context.Add(machine);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(PostMachine), 
            new { id = machine.Machine_Qr }, machine);
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Add(machine);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(PostMachine), 
            new { id = machine.Machine_Qr }, machine);
    }
    
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Machine>> PostMachine(Machine machine)
{
    var mach = new Machine();
    _context.machines.Add(machine);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(PostMachine), new { id = mach.Machine_Qr}, mach);
}
```

I can't find a solution to display the image on the client side.

Comment: @Jason can you check this?

Comment: if the file is saved in a a publicly accessible folder, you can just use the url of the file.  Otherwise you will need to provide a REST endpoint that will return the image, or create a handler to return the image.

Comment: I stored it as an IFormFile because of that I didn't find a way to use the url of the file

Comment: I have no idea how that is relevant.  You have an image saved on your server.  You want to display it.  That is the core issue, and there are many existing questions that address it.  https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2523+display+image+on+server+site:stackoverflow.com